# TableView Cell -> UISearchBar : Sort Data, where the records which have most keywords matched should be shown first and then go towards the least

Tags: swift, sorting, uitableview, filter, uisearchbar

Search should sort results based on a number of matched keywords. It should show the most matched keyword results on top of the list, then the rest records going in descending order. I have a UITableView wherein I have implemented UISearchBar which is going to search my tableview cells as per query inserted in the search-box. Let me now recreate a scenario to explain it. Lets say my Api fetched different key value datas and among them is a key named as "**tags**" which will contain a string of comma separated values as "**dog, cat, pug**" now whenever user enters **dog** into the search-box as this value is shown in one of my tableview cell it will be shown as my tags contain value dog, again if we **insert second keyword as cat** the above record needs to be fetched and shown to the top and after that if there exists a record which contains only dog in one of the tag values or cat as one of the tag values then it needs to be shown after it. Similarly for third word.

Query -> Cat Dog Pug

1. It should show on the top only those records which have all of the above keywords
2. After that, it should show records where any two of the above values are present
3. After that, it should show single single records if there exists any from above keywords.

Please help.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("\(searchText)")
    
    let arrSearchTexts = searchText.components(separatedBy: " ")
    
    filteredStorage = originalStorage1.filter { (obj) -> Bool in
        if let tags = obj["tags"] as? String{
            var hasTag = false
            for searchedTag in arrSearchTexts{
                if tags.contains(searchedTag.lowercased()){
                    hasTag = true
                    break
                }
            }
            return hasTag //tags.contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        return false
    }
    
    
    //Sorting data

    filteredStorage.sort { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
        
        if let tags1 = obj1["tags"] as? String{
            var hasAllTags = true
            for tagVal in arrSearchTexts{
                if !tags1.contains(tagVal.lowercased()){
                    hasAllTags = false
                    break
                }
            }
            return hasAllTags
        }
        
        return obj1.contains { (obj) -> Bool in
            if let val = obj.value as? String,
               let firstTag = arrSearchTexts.last{
                return val.hasPrefix(firstTag)
            }
            return false
        }
    }
    
    if searchText == "" {
        filteredStorage = originalStorage1
    }
    
    tblView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `obj["tags"]` is a `String` or a `[String]`? It's unclear (name would suggest it's an array, but your code says it's a `String`). Also, why are you using `Dictionary`? Why not proper custom `struct`? That would avoid the casts... Give a sample of `obj`, how it's construct, etc.

Comment: obj["tags"] is an [String], using dictionary because my data is coming from an API and I need to store it

Comment: `obj["tags"]` is a `[String]`? How do you expect `obj1["tags"] as? String` to work then? Also, even if it comes from an API, we use models and custom struct to facilitate it. We parse API data... I strongly suggest you use a custom struct, it's easier later...

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0..<filteredStorage.count {
                var dict = filteredStorage[i]
                dict["priority"] = 0
                filteredStorage[i] = dict
            }
            
    for i in 0..<filteredStorage.count{
                let tagInArr : String = filteredStorage[i]["tags"] as! String
                var priorityInArr : Int = 0
                for tagVal in arrSearchTexts{
                    if tagInArr.contains(tagVal){
                        priorityInArr += 1
                    }
                }
                filteredStorage[i]["priority"] = priorityInArr
            }
    
    filteredStorage.sort{
        ((($0 as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["priority"] as? Int)!) > ((($1 as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["priority"] as? Int)!)
    }
```